# How do I force Socket.io to use the exact input address for connecting to my node server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, socket.io

I am using Nginx to host my Node backend and React frontend. React is hosted at the base http://localhost address. This means to connect to my backend I am required to type in http://localhost/backend to communicate with the node server. This is causing issues with socket.io where I have the following code:

```
export const socket = io("http://localhost/backend", {
  autoConnect: false,
  transports: ['polling', 'websocket'],
})
```

Where when I open network tab in chrome I can see that socket.io completely ignored the "/backend" and is failing to connect to this URL http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OZojOQ5. Any help with overriding this would be great. Sorry in advance if anything done wrong this is my first question.